# Why do two references to the same vector return different memory addresses for each element of the vector?

Tags: r

I'm learning R and currently I'm reading [this book](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#binding-basics). To make sure I understand the concept, I ran the following test which turned out to be quite confusing for me and I'd appreciate if you could clarify it. Here is the test, which I ran directly in the R shell from the terminal (not using RStudio or Emacs ESS).

```
> library(lobstr)
>
> x <- c(1500,2400,8800)
> y <- x
> ### So the following two lines must return the same memory address
> obj_addr(x)
[1] "0xb23bc50"
> obj_addr(y)
[1] "0xb23bc50"
> ### So as I expected, indeed both x and y point to the same memory 
> ### location: 0xb23bc50
>
>
>
> ### Now let's check that each element can be referenced by the same
> ### memory address either by using x or y
> x[1]
[1] 1500
> y[1]
[1] 1500
> obj_addr(x[1])
[1] "0xc194858"
> obj_addr(y[1])
[1] "0xc17db88"
> ### And here is exactly what I don't understand: x and y point 
> ### to the same memory address, so the same must be true for 
> ### x[1] and y[1]. So how come I obtain two different memory
> ### addresses for the same element of the same vector?
>
>
>
> x[2]
[1] 2400
> y[2]
[1] 2400
> obj_addr(x[2])
[1] "0xc15eca0"
> obj_addr(y[2])
[1] "0xc145d30"
> ### Same problem!
>
>
>
> x[3]
[1] 8800
> y[3]
[1] 8800
> obj_addr(x[3])
[1] "0xc10e9b0"
> obj_addr(y[3])
[1] "0xc0f78e8"
> ### Again the same problem: different memory addresses
```

Could you tell me where my mistake is and what I've misunderstood in this problem?

Comment: I don't know R but in other languages you have value and reference types. If integer is value type as in C++ or C# then any assignment will create new integer. So every integer will have own address.

Comment: Indeed, even running `obj_addr(x[1])` twice should give you different results, as every new integer will have its own address.

Comment: @Bas I tested what you mentioned, that is, running successively obj_addr(x[1]), and indeed doing so, R returns each time a different result (different memory address). But I don't understand why, because as it seems to me I don't assign anything, so I don't create a new object (for which obviously there will be a new address as objects are immutable in R). For me obj_addr(x[1]) means that I'm just reading an already existing object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any R object is a C (pointer -called `SEXP`- to a) "multi-object" (`struct`). This includes information (that R needs to operate, e.g. `length`, number of references -to know when to copy an object- and more) about the R object and, also, the actual data of the R object that we have access to.

`lobstr::obj_addr`, presumably, returns the memory address that a `SEXP` points to. That part of the memory contains both the information about *and* the data of the R object. From within the R environment we can't/don't need to access the (pointer to the) memory of the actual data in each R object.

As Adam notes in his answer, the function `[` *copies* the nth element of the data contained in the C object to a new C object and returns its `SEXP` pointer to R. Each time `[` is called, a new C object is created and returned to R.

We can't access the memory address of each element of the actual data of our object through R. But playing a bit around, we can trace the respective addresses using the C api:

A function to get the addresses:

```
ff = inline::cfunction(sig = c(x = "integer"), body = '
             Rprintf("SEXP @ %p\\n", x);

             Rprintf("first element of SEXP actual data @ %p\\n", INTEGER(x));

             for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH(x); i++) 
                 Rprintf("<%d> @ %p\\n", INTEGER(x)[i], INTEGER(x) + i);

             return(R_NilValue);
     ')
```

And applying to our data:

```
x = c(1500L, 2400L, 8800L)  #converted to "integer" for convenience
y = x

lobstr::obj_addr(x)
#[1] "0x1d1c0598"
lobstr::obj_addr(y)
#[1] "0x1d1c0598"

ff(x)
#SEXP @ 0x1d1c0598
#first element of SEXP actual data @ 0x1d1c05c8
#<1500> @ 0x1d1c05c8
#<2400> @ 0x1d1c05cc
#<8800> @ 0x1d1c05d0
#NULL
ff(y)
#SEXP @ 0x1d1c0598
#first element of SEXP actual data @ 0x1d1c05c8
#<1500> @ 0x1d1c05c8
#<2400> @ 0x1d1c05cc
#<8800> @ 0x1d1c05d0
#NULL
```

The successive memory difference between our object's data elements equals the size of `int` type:

```
diff(c(strtoi("0x1d1c05c8", 16), 
       strtoi("0x1d1c05cc", 16), 
       strtoi("0x1d1c05d0", 16)))
#[1] 4 4
```

Using the `[` function:

```
ff(x[1])
#SEXP @ 0x22998358
#first element of SEXP actual data @ 0x22998388
#<1500> @ 0x22998388
#NULL
ff(x[1])
#SEXP @ 0x22998438
#first element of SEXP actual data @ 0x22998468
#<1500> @ 0x22998468
#NULL
```

This might be a more than needed extensive answer and is simplistic on the actual technicalities, but, hopefully, offers a clearer "big" picture.

Comment: Awesome! I really thank you very much for such detailed and clear explanation for people like me who are completely beginners in R. Also, your example is very impressive in showing the flexibility of R and its possible powerful interactions with other programming languages. Many thanks for your time and your help.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to look at it. I am sure there is a more technical view. Remember that in R, nearly everything is a function. This includes the extract function, `[`. Here is an equivalent statement to `x[1]`:

```r
> `[`(x, 1)
[1] 1500
```

So what you are doing is running a function which returns a value (check out `?Extract`). That value is an integer. When you run `obj_addr(x[1])`, it is evaluating the function `x[1]` and then giving you the `obj_addr()` of that function return, not the address of the first element of the array that you bound to both `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your attention to my problem. Indeed this is what I didn't know, that is, retreiving a value by "Extract" indeed creates a new object. As I said I'm really a beginner in R! Thank you very much for your time and your description.